# what will happen when codes in pod is running while hpa scale down?

Tags: kubernetes, autoscaling, hpa

I'm learning k8s hpa autoscale and have one confusion。

if there are some codes run in pod like this:

```py
# do something1
time.sleep(15)
# do something2
```

when execution come to time.sleep(15) and at this time the hpa scale down, will this pod be removed and something2 will not execute？

Comment: When HPA scale down pod it will not execute anything afterwords and kills the running process in your pod/container.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There as a few options as to how can you control what should happen when your service goes down. Typically, K8S will send a `soft termination` to the container's main process, which the process can use to handle gracefully(intercept interrupt signals).
Although, K8S will only wait for `terminationGracePeriod` time defined in the PodSpec.

You can also use a lifecycle hook called `preStop` and handle the service termination process externally.

Some information is here in this StackOverflow answer: [Is there a way to downscale pods only when message is processed (the pod finished its task) with the HorizontalPodAutoscaler in Kubernetes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56552175/is-there-a-way-to-downscale-pods-only-when-message-is-processed-the-pod-finishe)

Read the Kubernetes documentation about the pod termination process with respect to service management and pod lifecycle.
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#pod-termination

To answer your question,  it will depend on `terminationGracePeriod` on whether or not `something2` will execute.